# r stars: calculate ndvi for every time step on stars proxy

Tags: stars

I would like to calculate the ndvi on every time step of a 4d data cube (x, y, bands, time) in on an stars proxy object. 
Do you have any ideas of how to achieve this on the proxy object?
My current approach throws the error:

> Error in ds[-MARGIN] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Here is the code that produces this error:

```
tif = system.file("tif/L7_ETMs.tif", package = "stars")
t1 = as.Date("2018-07-31")
x_prox = read_stars(c(tif, tif, tif, tif), 
               along = "time", 
               RasterIO = list(nXOff = c(1), 
                               nYOff = c(1), 
                               nXSize = 50, 
                               nYSize = 50, 
                               bands = c(1:6)), 
               proxy = TRUE)
x_prox = stars::st_set_dimensions(.x = x_prox, which = "time", 
                                  values = c(t1, t1+1, t1+2, t1+3))
st_dimensions(x_prox)
st_get_dimension_values(x_prox, "time")

calc_ndvi = function(x) (x[2] - x[1])/(x[2] + x[1])
x_prox = st_apply(X = x_prox, MARGIN = c("x", "y", "time"), FUN = calc_ndvi)
x_prox_ndvi = st_as_stars(x_prox)
```

Changing `proxy = FALSE` returns correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed by the developers of the stars package. See this [issue](https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/issues/231).
The code works now.